# Mockito: Mocking an object that has more than one constructor?

Tags: java, mockito

Is it possible to mock an object that might be instantiated in the class under test which does not use dependency injection and will be instantiated with a different constructor depending upon the c-tor used for the class under test?

Answer (score 1):

Your mocks don't actually invoke the constructor.  They invoke a proxy object of sorts, which will resolve to that object type but is injected with a lot of runtime utilities to allow you to inspect it.

If you *want* to test your constructors, then you would want to actually instantiate it without a mock.

Answer (score 1):

Think of constructor invocations as the static calls that they are: If you call `new Foo(...)` in your code, Mockito will not be able to provide a replacement or mock `Foo` (at least without rewriting your system-under-test, [which is what Powermock can do](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor)). This is true regardless of how many constructors Foo has.

If you aren't allowed to change your system-under-test, you're stuck: It's just not a flexible system as it is. This isn't necessarily a bad thing: If your system's dependency is lightweight and resilient, you might instead just make sure the dependency is well-tested and treat it as an unchangeable implementation detail of your system-under-test.

If you want to replace your instance with a mock, you will probably need to insert a *testing seam* where you can get in and replace the instance, which is a sort of dependency injection. You might choose to do so with a factory, which can be kept as a field or passed in as a constructor argument:

```
class YourSystemUnderTest {
  interface FooFactory {
    Foo create(Bar bar);           // one-arg constructor
    Foo create(Bar bar, Baz baz);  // two-arg constructor
  }

  class DefaultFooFactory implements FooFactory {
    @Override public Foo create(Bar bar) { return new Foo(bar); }
    @Override public Foo create(Bar bar, Baz baz) { return new Foo(bar, baz); }
  }

  /** Visible and non-final for testing. */
  FooFactory fooFactory = new DefaultFooFactory();  // replace this in tests

  // ...
}
```

Or, as a slightly more-hacky way to do this, delegate to an overridable method call in your system-under-test, and override that in your test.

```
class YourSystemUnderTest {
  /** Visible and non-final for overriding. */
  Foo createFoo(Bar bar) { return new Foo(bar); }
  /** Visible and non-final for overriding. */
  Foo createFoo(Bar bar, Baz baz) { return new Foo(bar, baz); }
}

class YourSystemUnderTest_Test {
  @Mock Foo mockFoo;

  @Before void createSystemUnderTest() {
    yourSystemUnderTest = new YourSystemUnderTest() {
      @Override Foo createFoo(Bar bar) { return mockFoo; }
      @Override Foo createFoo(Bar bar, Baz baz) { return mockFoo; }
    };
  }

  // ...
}
```

Note that in both cases, you are accurately representing that YourSystemUnderTest is no longer to locked to only using a real Foo instance, but rather that it is allowed to use other implementations of Foo including test-double implementations. Outside of tests, this may come in handy if you ever upgrade or change your system-under-test's dependencies.